# Go over/through vs look over/through

Tags: word-difference

I'd like to know the difference(s) between the verbs go over, go through, look over and look through.There are other words  that have similar meaning to these verbs too but I chose to compare these verbs because they contains the same prepositions, which are over and through, so this is very confusing for learners.

Here are the definitions by Oxford Dictionary

**Go over** :Consider, examine, or check (something)

**Go through** :Search through or examine methodically

**Look over** : Inspect something with a view to establishing its merits

**Look through** : Peruse (a book or other written material)

What I observe is that dictionaries cluster their synonyms as  search and examine.

I am familiar with the verb **go over** that is used to mean study before exams and I think the verb **go through** implies more detailed examination whereas **look over** means more like **check out** (appearance of something) quickly or superficially more than a office document which contains financial figures.

I read also these verbs may have an ambiguous meaning without a context but let's go over them.

Some examples from various dictionaries:

In the competition, the judge **goes over** each dog and assesses it.

Dave **went through** his pockets looking for the keys.

Customs officers **went through** all my bags.

Forensic ​scientists are **going over** the victim's ​flat in a ​search for ​clues about the ​murderer.

We're are still **going over** the ​details of the ​contract.

It's a good ​idea to get someone to **go over** ​your ​application ​form before you ​submit it.

Do you have a few minutes to **look** these samples **over**?

Students were given five minutes to look through the examination paper before they were told the start writing.

Comment: Intuitively, while fairly interchangeable, I would consider **going through** to be more intensive (and potentially more invasive, depending on the object of the sentence) than **going over**. It is really the object of the sentence that complicates matters, as some occasions of use (such as *going over a contract* vs. *going through a contract*) are slightly metaphorical if you think about the prepositions literally; there's also the fact that literal use of some prepositions sounds weird (e.g. a judge could more intensively inspect a dog, but they would still not *go through* the dog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any good Chinese menu

> Column A
>   **Go
>
>   Look**
>
> Column B
>   **Over
>
>   Through**

The terms

> have a **look**

means to see what is visible on the surface, not too much involvement

> have a **go** (BrE)

means to try to do something, which mean more involvement

> gloss **over**

means to superficially cover

> plough **through**

means to use effort (to move dirt around, in the literal example)

In order of intensity of activity (one from column A, one from column B)

> Look over
>   Look through
>   Go over
>   Go through

Arguably, in your dictionary sentences, one could say

> Forensic ​scientists are **going through** the victim's flat
>   We're are still **going through** the ​details of the contract